# How to create multiple "user message" for every step in validation?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want to create multiple user message at every step of my validation.

I have created a validation for recurring task in task list. Now I want to create specific user message at every column wherever the validation condition does not satisfy and stops.

Comment: information is insufficient. Provide more details

Comment: In my task list I have create a recurring task columns and I have created a validation settings . If validation goes wrong it shows a "user message" which I have created but I want to create custom message where it will show the message specific to the column in my recurring task form . So I will know where exactly I a going wrong in filling the value in my form !

Comment: so what is it, a custom form created in designer, just u want the validation for input in that field, correct me if I am wrong in understanding the requirement

Comment: Thankyou for your interest . Let me explain it with an example ...
This is a small validation setting which I have input 
=If([Recurrence Interval]=Weekly,AND([Recurring Day]>0,[Recurring Day]<8)
And the user message I created for this is "Check your recurring task values !! "
But what I want is that if there is some problem in my recurring interval it should show specific user message and and if recurring day is wrongly input it should again show specific user message !

Comment: Sounds like you want different error message depending on what is wrong. Best way I can think of is to add your own javascript to the page and have the error appear as an alert pop up box

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want !!
Since I am not a coder is it possible if I can do it in sharepoint designer ?
and if javascript needs to be used ,where to write code for it and add it will our list ?

Comment: you can create custom form using designer , add javascript in headsection, or create seperate javascript file, and add its reference to your custom page.. you can google any of above steps to see elaboration of it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

1. Go to the list settings >> Validation Settings.
2. Set formula:

   ```
   =IF([Recurrence Interval]="Weekly",IF(AND([Recurrence
   Day]>0,[Recurrence Day]<8),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
   ```
3. Type user message: `Check your recurring task values !`
4. Save it and test form.

Comment: My validation settings and other things are correct , All I want is 
Rather than showing generalised user msg"Check your recurring task values !!"  I want to customise it to that it will show me only particular error  .

Comment: Ok so multiple message for multiple custom condition. Right?

Comment: yes exactly !! kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You could add custom form using SharePoint designer. And use function PreSaveAction() in javascript. This function helps in validating the fields before Save.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() 
{ 
   if(validation==fails)
   {
    alert("Message");
    return false;
   }
   else
   {  
    return true;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and recommended option would be to use JSLink to show custom error messages. Please follow the [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-80cc9b05) link for detailed explanation.